# Access same object between different files from Node module

Tags: node.js, express, winston

I can't find anywhere to tell me that this is completely wrong so here I go:

In my module I have two functions:

- init: create the winston logger object
- get: returns the object

I have several files which need to use the logger object.
In these files, I'm requiring the module, and using the get function.

I want to initialize it once. Then in other files, I want to simply require the module, get the object, and use it. Is my logic completely wrong here? I can pass it to the other modules, but I thought this would be a clean way of using the logger.

Currently in the file where I `init` and `get` the logger, I can use it just fine. Once I'm in a new file/module, the `get` returns `undefined` which leads me to believe this is incorrect.

Comment: You can require it in the entry point of your application and dependency inject the object to the required files.See https://blog.risingstack.com/dependency-injection-in-node-js/

Comment: An example would be nice!

Comment: Do you need to pass arguments to init?

Comment: By the way showing your code as it is now would us help to modify it and adjust it to your requirements.